# TypeError: string argument without an encoding

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-datalab

I want to upload compressed gzip of Json into Google Storage.

I have this code:

```
import datalab.storage as storage
import gzip
path = prefix + '/orders_newline.json.gz'
storage.Bucket('orders').item(path).write_to(gzip.compress(bytes(create_jsonlines(source)),encoding='utf8'), 'application/json')
```

The `create_jsonlines(source)` is a function that returns Json Newline Delimited.

Running this code gives:

```
TypeError: string argument without an encoding
```

The [Python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-bytes) says the format is: `bytes([source[, encoding[, errors]]])` I'm not sure I understand it as there is no example of how to use it.

I tried also

```
bytes([(create_jsonlines(source))[,encoding='utf8']])
```

This gives :

```
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I'm running Python 3.5

Comment: the issue with this immediate code example is the encoding arg was in the wrong function.

Answer (score 115, accepted):

You are not using the `bytes` function correctly. Check this:

```
>>> a = "hi"
>>> bytes(a, encoding='utf8')
b'hi'
```

You can try:

```
bytes((create_jsonlines(source)), encoding='utf8')
```

`encoding` is the argument of the `bytes` function, and you are using it outside of that function.

Comment: you can just do `str.encode()` without specifying an encoding

Answer (score 7):

You are probably only one step away from the answer.

See [bytearray()](https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/functions.html#bytearray) and [bytes](https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/functions.html#bytes) for the function usage (you may need to change python version of the document).

And it says:

> The optional source parameter can be used to initialize the array in a
> few different ways:
>
> - If it is a string, you must also give the encoding (and optionally, errors) parameters; bytearray() then converts the string to bytes
>   using str.encode().
> - If it is an integer, the array will have that size and will be initialized with null bytes.
> - If it is an object conforming to the buffer interface, a read-only buffer of the object will be used to initialize the bytes array.
> - If it is an iterable, it must be an iterable of integers in the range 0 <= x < 256, which are used as the initial contents of the
>   array.

Notice that the square bracket indicates that those parameters can be omitted, it is not an array type of python language.

So you should use `bytes(create_jsonlines(source), encoding='utf8')`.

Answer (score 3):

When you read any python function docs as

```py
bytes([source[, encoding[, errors]]])
```

square brackets represent that those parameters are optional. multiple square brackets inside another mean they are next level of option params. For example

```
bytes([source....
```

means we can call bytes as byes() itself as `[source]` is optional here

```
bytes() -> empty bytes object
```

```
bytes(22)
```

Here 22 is being passed as the source

read this for more details about bytes and its params

https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes