# TypeError : "errorMessage": "argument should be a bytes-like object or ASCII string, not 'Binary'",

Tags: python, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, boto3, amazon-kms

I tried another program to validate the saved list of username and encrypted password from the above table and username and allowed resources in a different table. This program needs to be integrated with API request, however I have changed to send event test parameters from lambda test config, I tried the same for decoding as guided in the previous comments.
Based on the previous error and comments, I was able to resolve that.
["errorMessage": "string argument without an encoding",](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59584558/errormessage-string-argument-without-an-encoding/59584705#59584705)
[TypeError: string argument without an encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51961386/typeerror-string-argument-without-an-encoding)

This seemes to be same kind of issue. However I tried with below formats. The errors remains same for all three.

```
CiphertextBlob=bytes(base64.b64decode(secret, 'utf8')
CiphertextBlob=bytes(base64.b64decode(secret).decode('utf8'))
CiphertextBlob=bytes(base64.b64decode(secret), decoding='utf8')
```

---

```
Response:
{
  "errorMessage": "argument should be a bytes-like object or ASCII string, not 'Binary'",
  "errorType": "TypeError",
  "stackTrace": [
    "  File \"/var/task/lambda_function.py\", line 45, in lambda_handler\n    decrypted_password_from_table = decrypt(session,password_from_table)\n",
    "  File \"/var/task/lambda_function.py\", line 10, in decrypt\n    CiphertextBlob=bytes(base64.b64decode(secret).decode('utf8'))\n",
    "  File \"/var/lang/lib/python3.8/base64.py\", line 80, in b64decode\n    s = _bytes_from_decode_data(s)\n",
    "  File \"/var/lang/lib/python3.8/base64.py\", line 45, in _bytes_from_decode_data\n    raise TypeError(\"argument should be a bytes-like object or ASCII \"\n"
  ]
}
```

---

```
import os
import boto3
import base64
from boto3.dynamodb.conditions import Key, Attr
#import botocore.vendored.requests.api as requests

def decrypt(session, secret):
    client = session.client('kms')
    plaintext = client.decrypt(
        CiphertextBlob=bytes(base64.b64decode(secret), decoding='utf8')
    )
    return plaintext["Plaintext"]

def lambda_handler(event, context):

    session = boto3.session.Session()
    dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb')
    authentication_table_name = 'Authentication'
    authorization_table = dynamodb.Table('Authorization')
    authentication_table = dynamodb.Table(authentication_table_name)

    # Extract the username, password, and resource from the message

    #message = str(event['message'])
    #password = message.split('password>')[1][:-2]
    #username = message.split('username>')[1][:-2]
    #resource = message.split('resource>')[1][:-2]

    password = event['password']
    username = event['username']
    resource = event['resource']

    #print('MESSAGE: ' + message)
    #print('PASSWORD: ' + str(password))
    #print('USERNAME: ' + str(username))
    #print('RESOURCE: ' + str(resource))

    # Authenticate user with encrypted DDB

    entry = authentication_table.get_item(TableName=authentication_table_name, Key={'username':username})

    if 'Item' in entry:
        #print('entry["Item"]["password"]: ' + str(entry['Item']['password']))
        password_from_table = entry['Item']['password']
        decrypted_password_from_table = decrypt(session,password_from_table)
        #decrypted_password_from_table = decrypted_password_from_table.decode('utf-8')
        print('type(decrypted_password_from_table): ' + str(type(decrypted_password_from_table)))
        print('attempted password: ' + str(password))
        print('decrypted_password_from_table: ' + str(decrypted_password_from_table))
        if password == decrypted_password_from_table:
            print('User has been authenticated.')
        else:
            print('Incorrect password')
            return 'Incorrect password'
    else:
        print('User is NOT VALID')
        return 'Invalid User'

    # Authorize user with unencrypted DDB

    allowed_resources = authorization_table.get_item(Key={'username': username})['Item']['allowed_resources']
    allowed_resources = allowed_resources.split(',')
    print('allowed_resources: ' + str(allowed_resources))
    if resource not in allowed_resources:
        return 'USER NOT AUTHORIZED TO ACCESS RESOURCE'

    # Forward message to endpoint
    #response = requests.request('GET', 'https://postman-echo.com/get?foo1=bar1', params={'foo1': message})
   # print('dummy echo api response.text: ' + str(response.text))

    return_string = 'Success! Here is your API response: ' #+ str(response.text)
    return return_string
```

Comment: What type is `secret` of?

Comment: It's a string encrypted password from another table, the link which I've mentioned in the post will show the previous program which i used to save encrypted password to a table

Comment: So is it of type `str` or `bytes`?

Comment: In the previous program, Password was saved after encrypting and encoded into utf8 format, however the item's format was string in the table.

Comment: Sorry my bad, it's in binary

Comment: So it's of type `bytes`? I mean, if it's feasible for run, what does `>>> type(secret)` output on the interpreter?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205343/discussion-between-chandan-and-sam-chats).